# Fastreport field properties from preview screen

Tags: fastreport

In my application, I create the reports from source code by using fast report.
I wish to give the user the ability to modify the report by using the fast report designer.
Once the changes done by the user, how I can read the preview screen and find properties of certain fields, such as left, top, width, font etc.
TfrxMemoview(report.components[I]).left always results the original value, not the revised.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You will have to recreate the preview. The preview is already what you want to print. If you do not like what you see recreate it. But it is possible to read all properties from the preview.